# How to get frames from webcam using OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to get frames form a Logitech C920 camera
and show them.

The camera seems to be working but nothing is being shown on the display window.

I tried to configure all the camera settings but nothing.
What am I missing???

```cpp
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2\imgcodecs.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core.hpp"
#include "opencv2\highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2\videoio.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    VideoCapture camera(CAP_ANY);

    Mat frame;
    namedWindow("x", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

    camera.set(CAP_PROP_FOURCC, VideoWriter::fourcc('M', 'J', 'P', 'G'));
    camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1920);
    camera.set(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1080);

    while (1)
    {
        camera.read(frame);
        imshow("x", frame);
    }

    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put `waitKey(int delay)` after each frame. Your `while` loop should look like this:

```
while (1)
    {

        camera.read(frame);
        imshow("x", frame);
        waitKey(1);

    }
```